# Penrose thesis topics?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a place where I could know the titles of the chapters of R. Penrose thesis Tensor methods in algebraic geometry? Does an alternative to CUP library exist for old thesis? I managed Hawking's thesis (now online) but I don't know how to get Penrose's...Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Google finds [this](https://dds.crl.edu/crldelivery/5476).  Your institution must be a member of the Center for Research Libraries.

Comment: I found the same, but my institution doesn't seem to be a member. It would be nice to know of other places where it might be publicly accessible, if those exist.